# Unable to get thunderbird mail to work with comcast

Tags: email, thunderbird

Comcast killed port 110 back in December, now thunderbird mail won't work.Changed setting for pop3 to new port 995. still no work. Setup an imap also, still same results.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change SSL type from to "none" to SSL/TLS and leave the Authentication field set to Autodetect. Better yet try to setup a new profile with imap settings that will likely be auto-detected and use the same settings with your already configured account.